# Encountering "Type Error: 'float' object is not subscriptable when using a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 'Undergraduate' Series in my dataframe that I'm trying to iterate over and split everything left of the comma into a 'Bachelor...' and 'University Name' and I'm running into a Python TypeError where when I put it through a loop, it's returning a 'float' object is not subscriptable despite it being a string. There's probably an easier way to do what I'm doing, but I used this technique in a different project and it worked successfully, so I'm trying to reuse what I did.

The code:

```
undergrad = df['Undergraduate'].str.split(',')
```

Returns:

```
0      [Bachelor of Arts/Science,  Shanghai Jiaotong ...]
1      [Bachelor of Arts/Science,  University of Flor...
2      [Bachelor of Arts/Science,  University of Cinc...
3        [Bachelor of Arts/Science,  Harvard University]
4      [Bachelor of Arts/Science,  University of Puge...
```

And used this loop:

```
eduList = []

for item in undergrad:
    school = item[0][1]
    eduList.append(school)
```

Returned this error:

```
TypeError            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-4131c28b2fb3> in <module>()
      2 
      3 for item in undergrad:
----> 4     school = item[0][1]
      5     eduList.append(school)

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

When I checked the dtypes, it said object as well. Not sure what the issue is. Thank you in advance for all the help!

Comment: The error message tells you that either `item` or `item[0]` is a float. Without a [mcve], it is hard to say why.

Comment: If you could show how `undergrad` is constructed, that would help us determine why this error appears. Alternatively, if you tried printing `item` and `item[0]` it may become clear to you immediately.

Comment: You might have an `np.NaN` that is causing this error as `np.NaN` is a float

Comment: Simon, Joe B: Thanks for the help! I added a print(item) and it returned a null value. Can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your data have None record,you should check which row causes this error.
I find that your code maynot reach your goal.Beacuse `item[0][1]` just represents a  character as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
Undergraduate_list = ["Bachelor of Arts/Science,Shanghai Jiaotong","Bachelor of Arts/Science,University of Flor..."]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Undergraduate":Undergraduate_list})

undergrad = df['Undergraduate'].str.split(',')

eduList = []

for item in undergrad:
    print(item[0],item[0][1])
```

the output is:

```
Bachelor of Arts/Science a
Bachelor of Arts/Science a
```

if you want to get degree,you can do this:

```
eduList,universityList = undergrad.str[0],undergrad.str[1]
print(eduList)
```

you will get:

```
0    Bachelor of Arts/Science
1    Bachelor of Arts/Science
Name: Undergraduate, dtype: object
```

Comment: You were right, my data had some null values that I then dropped and then ran the loop which resulted in what I wanted. Thank you!