# How to split() the members of a str column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

I have a dataframe with a column of strs all of the form '9xqv42x_general'. I need to extract (and have done a great many experiments trying) the geohash part from the string into a new column.

My attempts look something like:
`df['geohasheything'].str.split('_')[0]`
but these always seem to end with the error: "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"

How does a float even enter in to it? We're talking about a str.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example ?

Comment: Try `df['geohasheything'].str.split('_').str[0]` instead. Use the .str accessor to get the first element of a list.

Comment: Ultimately what worked for me was `df_snowflake_pl['geohasheything'].str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have a null value in the dataframe? If those are all strings with one null value, similar to np.NaN, you will get a float error as [np.NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54338851/encountering-type-error-float-object-is-not-subscriptable-when-using-a-list) is a float.

If you drop those, the line you have should work.